# AWS MySQL DB instance - I cannot access the DB using my MySQL client

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

The place where I work has been trialling AWS so I decided to create a new MySQL DB instance. I selected that it should be publicly available + default VPC (i.e. I didn't create or use a custom one) and I selected the default VPC security groups.

When I tried to access the instance from my laptop using a MySQL client, it's timing out.

I've verified the settings that I should be able to access it. But it's not happening. Any ideas what I could've done wrong? Thanks

**some screenshots:**

screen saying it's authorized
[image: screen saying it's authorized]

selected security group
[image: selected security group]

Comment: not sure for the downvote. seems it's programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security group rule in your screenshot is only allowing access to network traffic that originates from instances within the security group that starts with "sg-6db4" (your screenshot cuts off the full security group ID). In other words only EC2 instances in that one security group are being allowed access to your database right now.

Try adding another security group rule using the "My IP" option for the source value.